# Is there a way to skip/bypass a Mongodb aggregation stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having a problem with MongoDB query. My query to MongoDB database is:

```
    Places.aggregate([
      Stage-A
      { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": coord
      },
        "spherical": true,
        "maxDistance" : maxDistance,
        "query": {tags:{$all:tags}},
        "limit": resultLimit,
        "distanceField": "distance"
      }
    },
    {Stage-B = check is stage-A have found any documents},
    {Stage-C},
    {Stage-D}
  ])
```

I want to check If the stage-A has found any results, if not, I want to move to stage-C with a different query. If Stage-A finds results, then I will directly move to final stage-D. My hypothetical aggregate query looks like this :

```
Places.aggregate([
    Stage-A
   { 
     "$geoNear": {
       "near": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": coord
     },
       "spherical": true,
       "maxDistance" : maxDistance,
       "query": {tags:{$all:tags}},
       "limit": resultLimit,
       "distanceField": "distance"
     }
    },
    Stage-B
    {
      In this stage-B, I want to check if the stage-A has found any results,
      if results, I want to move to the last stage-D, otherwise stage-C         then finally Stage-D
    },
    Stage-C
    {
      "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": coord
      },
        "spherical": true,
        "maxDistance" : maxDistance,
        "query": {tags:{$in:tags}}, >> different query
        "limit": resultLimit,
        "distanceField": "distance"
      }
    },
    Stage-D
    {
      $project:{

      }
    }
])
```

I was wondering if this logical flow is possible in MongoDB aggregate or something else. If so, what would be the stage-B? If not, what is the best way to solve this problem? I wanted to do all of these in a single request, so I can save some CPU cycles.

Comment: Are you sure it's even possible to have a Stage C with another $geoNear operator? The docs say that [You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/).

Comment: yeah, I have read the documents. That means,  we do not have any alternative solution of the problem.